# How to pass array of PETSc Vec to a function

Tags: c, petsc

I am trying to pass an **array** of Vec's in PETSc to a function, modify it internally and retrieve the results. A pseudocode is as follows:

```
    PetscErrorCode foo(Vec *y, int n) {

    // ...

       ierr = VecDuplicateVecs(x, n, &y);  CHKERRQ(ierr);
    // ...

       ierr = VecNorm(y[0],NORM_2,&norm); CHKERRQ(ierr);   // this prints out fine
       printf("norm = %f\n", norm);

    }

    int main(int argc,char **argv)
    {
        PetscErrorCode ierr;
        PetscScalar norm;
        Vec *y;

        foo(y, 3);

        ierr = VecNorm(y[0],NORM_2,&norm); CHKERRQ(ierr);     // this breaks: segfault

        ierr = VecDestroyVecs(3, &y); CHKERRQ(ierr);

        return 0;
    }
```

I am indeed getting a message from the compiler stating that `variable "y" is used before its value is set`, but I am failing to see how to pass these guys by reference. `VecDuplicateVecs` has to necessarily be initialized in main?

Comment: Your `Vec *y` is not initialized when you try to pass it to another function. What do you expect that function to receive? You probably want to pass the *address* of it instead.

Comment: @Chase: Does your comment imply I should call it as: `foo(&y, 3);`, and then later the call of the routine should be `PetscErrorCode foo(Vec **y, int n)`? Then inside the routine I would have to modify it as `ierr = VecDuplicateVecs(x, n, y);  CHKERRQ(ierr);`. I tried this in my application, and although works for the first entry of the array of Vec's, it gives me a segfault for other entries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were two problems: 1) The address of the pointer `*y` was not passed to foo [@Chase] . 2) a double pointer call would solve the issue in `VecNorm` within `foo()`

```
PetscErrorCode foo(Vec **y, int n) {

// ...

   ierr = VecDuplicateVecs(x, n, y);  CHKERRQ(ierr);
// ...

   ierr = VecNorm((*y)[0],NORM_2,&norm); CHKERRQ(ierr); 

   printf("norm = %f\n", norm);

}

int main(int argc,char **argv)
{
    PetscErrorCode ierr;
    PetscScalar norm;
    Vec *y;

    foo(&y, 3);

    ierr = VecNorm(y[0],NORM_2,&norm); CHKERRQ(ierr);     
    ierr = VecDestroyVecs(3, &y); CHKERRQ(ierr);

    return 0;
}
```